# file reading in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, filereader

I am trying to read a text file in java and write it on text area. It is reading the first line properly but once it encounters "enter" . it overwrites the content in the next line over the previous line.

Here is my code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    int val = jfc.showOpenDialog(jf);
                    int x=0;
                    String s;
                    if(val == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    {
                        File fs=jfc.getSelectedFile();
                        try
                        {
                            BufferedReader of=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fs));
                            while((s=of.readLine())!=null)
                            {

                                ja.setText(s.toString());
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cannot open the file");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all of your content of file using `BufferedReader of=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fs));` into one string and then do the `setText()`.

Dont do the setText inside the while loop, it will overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly add new line (`\n`).

```
BufferedReader of=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fs));
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
while((s=of.readLine())!=null){
      str.append(s+NEW_LINE);
}
ja.setText(str.toString());
```

And new line constant would be

```
public static final String NEW_LINE = "\n"
```

Comment: This code won't compile: 1. you can't initialize a `StringBuffer` with a string literal; 2. a `String` has no `append` method

Answer (score 1):

`JTextArea` has a inbulit `read()` method. It will be wise to use that (and easy way too)

```
try {
      FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("Path of your file"));
      yourTextArea.read(reader,"text");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex ) {
      Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

**Note :** `setText()` method replaces the current text with new text. So no result to call it in a loop .And taking care of your problem , automatically `newline` characters will be added to your `JTextArea`

Answer (score 0):

`JTextArea` has a `append` method, which will append content to the end of it's existing content.  `setText` will do just that, remove all previous text and replace it with new text.

You should also be making sure that your resources are closed properly

```
    File fs = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    try (BufferedReader of = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fs))) {
        while ((s = of.readLine()) != null) {
            ja.append(s + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot open the file");
    }
```

Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

simple change will make your code works:

```
   try {
      BufferedReader of = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fs));
      StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
      while ((s = of.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(s.toString()+"\n");      

      }
     ja.setText(sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot open the file");
    }finally {
      sb.close();
      fs.close();
      of.close();
    }
```

since you're reading line by line and setting the value to your textbox, it will surely override by next line you read. so append it just after the while loop.hope you will understand your issue.

Comment: I'd be nice it you closed the file when you were done with it

Answer (score -1):

Use Apache commons FileUtils class.

The below link will help you how to read the file content as string.
http://www.kswaughs.com/2015/05/how-to-read-file-into-string-in-java.html

Comment: And what if commons is not available?

Comment: @fge, I am wondering whether have you ever developed any java application without using any third-party frameworks or libraries. There is no such rule that you cannot use them. If he doesn't have commons api, he will download it and use it in his application. That's his choice. A problem can be solved in number of ways and My solution is one of them, Its up to him what to choose. Thank You.

Comment: I have actually. More to the point though, since Java 7, the file part of commons is basically obsolete.

Comment: Thank you @fge for the information. So far I used to work on Java 6 only. I didn't know that such feature available in java 7.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you face is that a `BufferedReader`'s `.readLine()` will kill all line separators it finds; and this is not what you want.

Use a more classical read method instead. Moreover, this is 2015, so use java.nio.file and try-with-resources:

```
private static final int BUFLEN = 8192;

public String readFileToString(final Path file)
    throws IOException
{
    final char[] buf = new char[MAXLEN];
    // Taking the file size as a default length is a good enough approximation
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Files.size(file));

    try (
        final Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ) {
        int charsRead;
        while ((charsRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1)
            sb.append(buf, 0, charsRead);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```